# Como usar "drawRect" para desenhar em um componente?

Tags: java, swing

Eu estou aprendendo `Graphics`, porém não consigo fazer um quadrado:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    JFrame tela = new JFrame("Snake");

    tela.setSize(500, 500);
    tela.setVisible(true);  

    Graphics g = tela.getGraphics();

    g.drawRect(5, 5, 50, 50);
}
```

Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que, se você precisa alterar a forma como um componente está sendo desenhado, é necessário redefinir o método `paintComponent`.

`getGraphics` vai te retornar um objeto `Graphics` em que, qualquer mudança feita (por exemplo, desenhar o quadrado) será temporária e você a perderá no primeiro momento que o Swing determinar que o componente deve ser repintado.

Então, uma forma de fazer isso sem herança — já respondido pelo Thiago Luiz — é sobrescrever o método `paintComponent` de um `JComponent` ou `JPanel` e então fazer todo o trabalho de pintura nesse método, usando o objeto `Graphics` recebido como argumento. Depois você pode adicionar o componente criado ao seu `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Snake");
        tela.setSize(500, 500);
        tela.setVisible(true); 

        JPanel painelComQuadrado = new JPanel(){
            // Sobrescrevendo o método 'paintComponent' do 'JPanel'.
            @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawRect(5, 5, 50, 50);
            }
        };
        tela.add(painelComQuadrado);

        // Chamando 'revalidate' e 'repaint' porque o painel com o
        // quadrado foi inserido no JFrame após o 'setVisible'.
        tela.revalidate();
        tela.repaint();
    }
}
```